# ImageMapster plugin is not working when I am rendering image , map and area tag through jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use ImageMapster plugin for my application. It works fine when using static image map in html. But my problem is that, when am rendering image and area tag through jquery, it is not working. I am using web api for getting attributes for image.

Here is my script :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       var iiim = "";
       var url = 'http://mobileappapi.azurewebsites.net/api/HomeApiImage';
       $.get(url, function (data) {
           iiim = data["BgImg"];
           var url = 'http://mobileappapi.azurewebsites.net/api/HomeApi';
           $.get(url, function (data) {


               $('#map_demo').prepend('<img  src="' + iiim + '" usemap="#usa" id="myimage" style="margin-top:43px;"/>')
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                   $('#usa_image_map').append('<area href="#" coords="' + data[i].Node_Location + '" state="n' + i + '" shape="rect" title="' + data[i].Node_Title + '" />')


               }
           }, "jsonp");

       }, "jsonp");


       $('#myimage').mapster({

           fillColor: 'ff0000',
           fillOpacity: 0.3
       });
   });
```

here is my html code,

```
 <body>
<div id="map_demo"> 
</div>
    <map id="usa_image_map" name="usa">
    </map>


 </body>
```

Please help me,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.get()` is an AJAX function; as such, it hasn't finished generating the new images before your `.mapster` method runs.

You have to put your `.mapster` call in your `.get` callback, after the image is created, to make sure it runs at the correct time.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var iiim = "";
    var url = 'http://mobileappapi.azurewebsites.net/api/HomeApiImage';
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        iiim = data["BgImg"];
        var url = 'http://mobileappapi.azurewebsites.net/api/HomeApi';
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#map_demo').prepend('<img  src="' + iiim + '" usemap="#usa" id="myimage" style="margin-top:43px;"/>')
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#usa_image_map').append('<area href="#" coords="' + data[i].Node_Location + '" state="n' + i + '" shape="rect" title="' + data[i].Node_Title + '" />')
            }
            $('#myimage').mapster({
                fillColor: 'ff0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.3
            });
        }, "jsonp");
    }, "jsonp");

});
```